# CSS breaking after adding conditional checks in return method for an unordered list

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am having a CSS issue in the header section.

Whenever I am adding the following check in my code to display a tab based on the condition, the whole header list is not showing in one horizontal line

```
<div>
                                {isAdmin(user) ?(

                                <div >
                                <li>
                                    <NavLink to="/datarequest">Data Request</NavLink>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <NavLink to="/datarequestperson">Person Data Request</NavLink>
                                </li>
                                </div>
                                
                                ) : (
                                <li>
                                    <NavLink to="/datarequest">Data Request</NavLink>
                                </li>

                                )
                                }
                                </div>
```

It works fine if I don't add the above part and just keep it like this - which I don't want since I want to hide a tab based on the condition:

```
                        <li>
                            <NavLink to="/datarequest">Data Request</NavLink>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <NavLink to="/datarequestperson">Person Data Request</NavLink>
                        </li>
```

The header-list class related css that I found in the code is as follows:

```
ul.header-list li {
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
}
ul.header-list {
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 0 15px 0 0;
    float: right;
    margin: 0px;
}
ul.header-list li a {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 20px 12px;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
    margin: 0 2px;        
}

ul.header-list li a.active, ul.header-list li a:hover{
    background: #0f5a25;
    color: #fff;
    transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: 0.3s ease-in-out; 
    cursor: pointer;       
}
```

What should I do to fix this so that I can also display the tabs based on the isAdmin condition and not break the css?

My `return` method in the code is as follows:

```
return (
    
    <div>
    {
        this.state.isAuthenticated ? (
            <BrowserRouter basename={process.env.REACT_APP_ROUTER_BASE || ''}>
                <div>
                    <div className="header">
                        <div className="header-logo">
                        <img src="images/mylogo.jpg"/>
                        <span>DATA GRID</span>
                        </div>

                        <div className="logout_sec">
                        <div className="logout_icon">
                            <a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick={this.logoutDialogOpen}> <FontAwesomeIcon
                                style={{fontSize: '1.5em'}} icon={faSignOutAlt}/></a>
                        </div>
                        </div>                                

                        <ul className="header-list">
                        <li>
                            <NavLink exact to="/">
                                Home
                            </NavLink>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <NavLink to="/myprojects">My Projects</NavLink>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <NavLink to="/myemployees">My Employees</NavLink>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <NavLink to="/mysystems">My Systems</NavLink>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <NavLink to="/mydoors">My Doors</NavLink>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <NavLink to="/unifiedwebservicedoc">Unified Web Services</NavLink>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <NavLink to="/datadictionarydoc">UAB Data Dictionary</NavLink>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <NavLink to="/expertise">People Finder</NavLink>
                        </li>
                        {/* <li>
                            <NavLink to="/datarequest">Data Request</NavLink>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <NavLink to="/datarequestperson">Person Data Request</NavLink>
                        </li> */}

                        <div>
                        {isAdmin(user) ?(

                        <div >
                        <li>
                            <NavLink to="/datarequest">Data Request</NavLink>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <NavLink to="/datarequestperson">Person Data Request</NavLink>
                        </li>
                        </div>
                        
                        ) : (
                        <li>
                            <NavLink to="/datarequest">Data Request</NavLink>
                        </li>

                        )
                        }
                        </div> 
                        <li>
                            <NavLink to="/datadownload">Download Builder</NavLink>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <NavLink to="/assetbrowser">Asset Browser</NavLink>
                        </li>
                    </ul>



                        {/* Popup COde start */}

                        {logoutDialog}
                        {/* Popup code End */}
                    </div>

                    <div id="forNotification"></div>
                    <div>
                        <Switch>
                            <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
                            <Route path="/myprojects"
                                   render={(props) =>
                                       <div>
                                           <Projects {...props}/>
                                       </div>
                                   }
                            />
                            <Route
                                path="/myemployees"
                                render={(props) =>
                                    <div style={{margin: '50px 150px auto'}}>
                                        <Employees
                                            {...props}
                                            url={properties.baseUrlWs + 'api/Employees/search/myurl?personnelId=' + personnelid}
                                            personnelid={personnelid}
                                            isMyEmployee={true}
                                        />
                                    </div>
                                }
                            />
                            <Route
                                path="/mysystems"
                                render={(props) =>
                                    <div style={{margin: '50px 150px auto'}}>
                                        <Systems
                                            {...props}
                                            url={properties.baseUrlWs + 'api/participantSets/search/myurl?value=' + personnelid}
                                            personnelid={personnelid}
                                            isMySystems={true}
                                        />
                                    </div>
                                }
                            />
                            <Route path="/mydoors" component={MyProtocols}/>
                            <Route exact path="/project" component={ProjectView}/>
                            <Route exact path="/analyst" component={Analyst}/>
                            <Route exact path="/unifiedwebservicedoc" component={UnifiedWebServiceDoc}/>
                            <Route exact path="/datadictionarydoc" component={DatadictionaryDoc}/>
                            <Route exact path="/expertise" component={Expertise}/>
                            <Route exact path="/datadownload" component={DataDownload}/>
                            <Route exact path="/assetbrowser" component={AssetBrowser}/>
                            <Route exact path="/datarequest" component={DataRequest}/>
                            <Route exact path="/datarequestperson" component={DataRequestPerson}/>
                            <Route path='/404' component={NotFoundPage}/>
                            <Redirect to="/404"/>
                        </Switch>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </BrowserRouter>
        ) : null
    }
    </div>
);
```

Comment: You have extra `div` in the first code snippets.

Comment: @Medi Are you referring to the `div` which is inside `{isAdmin(user) ?(` ?

Comment: If I remove the `div` from there, I get an error - ` Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Fragment`, `<>` or `[ele1, ele2]` for that to return multiple elements without any additional element wrapped after render like below.

```
{isAdmin(user) ? (
  <Fragment>
     <li>
       <NavLink to="/datarequest">Data Request</NavLink>
     </li>
     <li>
        <NavLink to="/datarequestperson">Person Data Request</NavLink>
     </li>
   </Fragment>
  ) : (
     <li>
        <NavLink to="/datarequest">Data Request</NavLink>
     </li>
```

Comment: Are you referring to use `Fragment` for the `div` above `{isAdmin(user) ? (` as well? I used like you suggested and it's still showing same behavior.

Comment: @Tan, Outer may not be required at all, you can remove that completely and try.

Comment: When I used it for the other div, it worked.

Comment: And you are right, outer one is not required. I just removed it completely and it still worked. Thanks !

Comment: One thing I noticed whenever I am clearing my cache and loading the website locally with the URL `localhost:3000`, I keep getting this error:`Uncaught SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
    isAdmin webpack:///./src/main/js/components/auth.js?:11
    render webpack:///./src/main/js/components/Main.js?:390`. However, when I comment the above check and uncomment it, it starts working fine. Do you know Why?

Comment: I don't think it's related to that, you need to check where you've used `JSON.parse` and what value did you pass to it?

Comment: I created a separate post with more detailed info. Please take a look. Thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67273146/getting-json-parse-unexpected-character-at-line-1-column-1-of-the-json-data-err

Comment: I wonder if values are not getting stored in session storage by the time it is trying to parse the JSON for assignee.